# How to use document.querySelector() with an arbitrary value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that will set up a "warp" (loading a new SVG map onto the screen) when the user clicks on the appropriate region on the map.  These regions have classes known as ".mapLink", and generally have additional classes to determine where they warp *to*; for example, `mapLink map001` will have this code get the second class, `map001` and run the `loadMap` function with that value.

I've recently set a second argument - the origin (changed to mapOrigin).  This stores the current map (in the `currentMap` variable, set in other code), and then before loading the new map, it stores it in the mapOrigin variable.

Once the map is loaded, it is supposed to get the X and Y values (and the width and height) values of whatever element has the class of `mapOrigin`, however Chrome gives the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')`

Here's the code:

```
$("#mapDisplay").on("click", ".mapLink" , function() {
    var selectedWarp = $(this).attr("class").replace("mapLink ", "");
    // console.log(`Warping to ${selectedWarp}...`);
    // var mapOrigin = document.querySelector(`.${currentMap}`);
    var mapOrigin = "." + currentMap;

    loadMap(selectedWarp, mapOrigin);
    
    // get coords of the origin once new map is loaded. Show the marker wherever the previous mapLink is on the new map
    console.log(`mapOrigin = ${mapOrigin}`);
    var originCoords = [
        document.querySelector(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().x + (document.querySelector(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().width/2),
        document.querySelector(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().y + (document.querySelector(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().height/2)
    ];
    $(`#mapMarker`).addClass("showMarker");
    $(`#mapMarker`).css("left", `${originCoords[0]}px`);
    $(`#mapMarker`).css("top", `${originCoords[1]}px`);

    // Clear the selected map class and apply it to whatever user clicked on.
    $("#mapsList a li").removeClass("selectedMap");
    $(`#${selectedWarp}`).addClass("selectedMap");
});
```

The mapLink Script:

```
var currentMap;  // Currently viewed map
function loadMap(mapID, origin) {
    /* Arguments:
        mapID
             -The map to load.  Example: "bn1ia01".
            - This ID applies to any associated file(s) (png, svg, js, etc).
        origin
            - OPTIONAL!
            - Specifies where a user came from if moving from one map to 
              another (Going from ACDC 1 to ACDC 2 via clicking the entrance 
              to ACDC 2 on the first map!)
    */
    // Clear contents of #mapDisplay...
    $(`#mapDisplay`).html("");
    $(`#mapNameDisplay`).html("")
    $(`#copyrightInfo`).html("");
    $(`#interactiveIndicator`).html("");
    currentMap = mapID;

    $.ajax({
        // url: `res/maps/${game}/${mapID}.bnmap`, // use this once I finalize the files.
        url: `res/maps/${game}/${mapID}.svg`,
        dataType: `xml`,
        success: function(data) {
            // Extract file contents
            var $svgContents = $(data).find("svg");
            var metadataInfo = new Array(
                $svgContents.find(`title:first`).text(),
                $svgContents.find(`author`).text(),
                $svgContents.find(`email`).text()
            );
  
            // Throw content into container
            $(`#mapDisplay`).html($svgContents);
            $(`#mapNameDisplay`).html(`Location: ${metadataInfo[0]}`)
            $(`#copyrightInfo`).html(`Map (C) ${metadataInfo[1]} (<a href="mailto:${metadataInfo[2]}">${metadataInfo[2]}</a>)`);
            // console.log(metadataInfo);
            $(`#interactiveIndicator`).html("INTERACTIVE MAP!");
        },
        error: function() {
            //const fs = require('fs');
            //const existsSvg = fs.existsSync(`res/maps/${mapID}.svg`);
            //const existsPng = fs.existsSync(`res/maps/${mapID}.png`);
            // console.log(`${game}/${mapID}.svg cannot be found.  Falling back to ${game}/${mapID}.png, instead.`)
            $(`#mapDisplay`).html(`<img src="res/maps/${game}/${mapID}.png">`);
            $(`#interactiveIndicator`).html("Static map only. Non-interactive.");
        }
    });

    // Map Marker - automatic handling if no origin specified
    if (!origin) {
        console.log(`function loadMap says "no origin specified - clear any map markers!"`);
        $(`#mapMarker`).removeClass("showMarker");  // Hide the map marker.
    }
};
```

My issue is this: If I were to type
`document.querySelector(".map001").getBoundingClientRect().x` in the developer console, as long as such a class exists it will return the value of the x position.

I have noticed that in certain pieces of code I've messed with in the past, it might seem like loading something, and then manipulating it has failed solely because of timing.  Even if it's in milliseconds (or shorter than that), I'll get an error programmatically, but if I manually step through things in the developer console, at the breakneck speed of manually typing each line in, things will do what I'm expecting it to do.

Assuming my hunch of what's wrong is correct, how can I store the value in `originCoords` only after the `loadMap()` function completes, and the map is properly loaded?

EDIT: Tried with using jQuery exclusively:

```
    var originCoords = [
        $(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().x + ($(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().width/2),
        $(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().y + ($(mapOrigin).getBoundingClientRect().height/2)
    ];
```

And I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: Why mix jQuery with the native browser `.querySelector()`? At least with jQuery you won't get those exceptions.

Comment: Also note that so far you're the only person who has any idea what `loadMap()` does.

Comment: @Pointy I added the loadMap script - it functions as intended though, which is why I omitted it but can see why it might be relevant, sorry!

As for JQuery, I remember trying it but I don't remember how I was trying to get values with jquery.

Comment: If timing is the issue, you might consider using a `MutationObserver` to listen for DOM changes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. You could add one inside `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` to listen for changes to the map container and do a check for `document.querySelector(".map001")` before taking action.

Comment: @Pointy I also added what I think I was trying to use for jQuery and what happens.

Comment: Well jQuery or not, you're going to have to add checks to verify that the elements you *expect* to be in the DOM are actually there.

Comment: Right, and `loadMap()` is asynchronous. It will not be finished when the `loadMap()` function call returns, so the code after that point in the "click" handler will certainly run before the ajax call has completed.

Comment: It looks to me like `currentMap` is empty until you run the loadMap function at least once.

Comment: jQuery returns a list of found elements, so you can't call getBoundingClientRect without first calling something like get(0).  $(mapOrigin).get(0).getBoundingClientRect().x

Comment: So currentMap is set elsewhere in the code and it reliably works, as I had it listing in the console.  loadMap is run in two situations.. clicking a map from a list (which ignores mapOrigin), or clicking a mapLink object.  This setup makes it impossible to have an empty value by the time the app needs to consider the value of "currentMap"

Answer (score 0):

You might be well served by reading up on asynchronous programming.

Two solutions to your issue:

1. Modify the loadMap function to take a callback, which it will execute once the map is loaded, harder to handle errors.
2. (Preferred) Modify loadMap to return a promise which is resolved when the map is loaded; then you can easily code loadMap().then().catch();